# Object getting updated inside "response.on", but updation is not getting reflected outside

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, get, javascript-objects

The object *result* does not get updated when I send it back to the front end.
At the front-end, it just shows that an empty object has been sent.

*url* is defined. The API call works correctly. The result when console logged inside *response.on* shows the correct behaviour. However, outside the *https* request it shows an empty object and the key value pairs are not added.

```
app.post("/getWeather",(req,res,next)=>{

    console.log(req.body.cities);

    const cities=req.body.cities;

    const result={};

    cities.map((city)=>{

        https.get(url,(response)=>{

            response.on("data",(data)=>{
                const wdata=JSON.parse(data);
                const temperature=wdata.main.temp;
                result[city]=temperature;
            });


        }).on("error",(err)=>{
            console.log(err);

            result[city]="NA";
        });
    });

    return res.json(result);

});
```

Result output at front-end = {}

Could someone please provide the corrected code?

Answer (score -1):

You need to wrap `https.get` calls into promises. The reason why `result` is an empty object at the return statement is because `https.get` is asynchronous, and you're not waiting for the `data` and `error` handlers to be called.

```js
app.post("/getWeather", async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.body.cities);

  const cities = req.body.cities;

  const result = {};

  const promises = [];

  cities.forEach((city) => {
    promises.push(
      new Promise((resolve) => {
        https
          .get(url, (response) => {
            response.on("data", (data) => {
              const wdata = JSON.parse(data);
              const temperature = wdata.main.temp;
              result[city] = temperature;
            });
          })
          .on("end", () => {
            resolve();
          })
          .on("error", (err) => {
            console.log(err);

            result[city] = "NA";

            resolve();
          });
      })
    );
  });

  await Promise.all(promises);

  return res.json(result);
});
```